# Android application to block calls and text messages in a cell phone

Tags: gratis, android

I need an Android application to block incoming calls and text messages in my cell phone for selected contacts.

Further specifications are:

1. The app should be free.
2. It should be able to block calls and text from more than 1 number.
3. The app must be easy to use.
4. If a call or text message from a blocked contact comes, the app should block it without any notification.
5. The blocked message should be deleted automatically(This is not necessary, but, if possible I need this feature too. Other 4 features are necessary).

Which application is the best ?

Comment: Though Android has a built-in feature for that, a number of 3rd party apps can be [found here](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=23#group_97). I have tried none of them, hence I cannot give a clear recommendation.

Comment: What do you mean multiple calls at a time?

Comment: @Mr.Alien Multiple numbers.

Comment: Do you want to block particular phone numbers, or reject all unknown numbers?

Comment: I want to block particular numbers actually. If you have a software to block particular numbers and a software to reject all unknown numbers, tell me both. I will choose the better for me. Try to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TrueCaller is the best app to block unwanted call and text messages. Also we can search unknown numbers in it and it gives details of about almost any number, from any country. Already there is a spam caller list in it and we became able to block those numbers when TrueCaller is installed. To download and use it just go to Google Play and search it.

Answer (score 5):

No need for an application. Go to dial application (the one you use to make the call) > call settings > Call rejection. To reject blocked numbers, just check 'unknown' in the auto reject at list.

Comment: Are you sure that this feature is present in all Android cell phones ?

Comment: It is present on my Android 4.1.2 (Samsung galaxy S3), I don't know about previous versions.

Comment: Isn't this feature dependant on your cell phone provider still?

Comment: @Virusboy I wouldn't guess so. What makes you think that way?